# how to cbind the column generated in a loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, cbind

I have a for loop that gives me a column of data per run. I run the for loop in the range 0:4, so it gives me 5 columns. If I print it out, it is like column1, column2, ... I want to save all of the 5 columns together as a csv file. In this one single file, I want to have the 5 columns ordered by the order of the for loop, namely, column1, column2, ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve what you have described.  Here is one approach that will work in many circumstances.

```
# start with an empty list
mydata <- list()

# run through your loop, adding each vector to the list
for(i in 1:10){
    # whatever is in your loop
    mydata[[i]] <- # result of this iteration of loop
}

# turn your list into a dataframe
mydf <- data.frame(mydata)

# write dataframe to a file
write.csv(mydf, file="destfile.csv")
```

Comment: This is a nice and simple way. Thanks a lot. Just want to give a feedback to anyone who will implement this piece of code. mydata[[i]] should be mydata[i], and I run it and get what I want. Thanks to tegancp!

Comment: The code works for me too. I'm just having problems to convert the list to data frame. I got the message `Error in data.frame(NULL, c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,  : arguments imply differing number of rows: 0,....` . Any help?

Answer (score 7):

Let's say you had a for loop like this:

```
for (i in 0:4) {
  this.column <- rep(i, 5)
}
```

To build a matrix out of the columns generated, you could change this to:

```
sapply(0:4, function(i) rep(i, 5))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    1    2    3    4
# [2,]    0    1    2    3    4
# [3,]    0    1    2    3    4
# [4,]    0    1    2    3    4
# [5,]    0    1    2    3    4
```

Basically you just create a function out of the interior of the for loop that takes the loop variable (`i` in this case) as input and returns the column. Then you call `sapply` with the loop indices and the first argument and the function as the second argument.

A fully vectorized approach could combine `matrix` and `rep`:

```
matrix(rep(0:4, each=5), nrow=5)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    1    2    3    4
# [2,]    0    1    2    3    4
# [3,]    0    1    2    3    4
# [4,]    0    1    2    3    4
# [5,]    0    1    2    3    4
```